# Do we need to build separately for each language when using alexa dialog model

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I changed interaction model in two languages and clicked save for each. Does clicking the build model cause both of them to build or just the language that is currently selected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to build interaction model specifically for each language but you can point all language to same Lambda function or HTTP endpint